# How to move a tag and its contents within xml with bsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have the following xml:

```
</Page>
<Page ID="Page2" PHYSICAL_IMG_NR="2" HEIGHT="3300" WIDTH="2550">
<TopMargin HEIGHT="151" WIDTH="2550" VPOS="0" HPOS="0">
</TopMargin>
<LeftMargin HE<IGHT="2771" WIDTH="143" VPOS="151" HPOS="0">
</LeftMargin>
<RightMargin HEIGHT="2771" WIDTH="143" VPOS="151" HPOS="2407">
</RightMargin>
<BottomMargin HEIGHT="378" WIDTH="2550" VPOS="2922" HPOS="0">
<TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
</BottomMargin>
<PrintSpace>
</PrintSpace>
</Page>
```

I want to move the `BottomMargin` tag and its content to the bottom of the xml (after the `PrintSpace` tag in this example) **for every `Page` tag**.

How do I do it?

I am reading the xml in the following way:

with open(xml, "r") as file:

```
content = file.readlines()
content = "".join(content)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`extract()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) and [`insert_after()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """</Page>
<Page ID="Page2" PHYSICAL_IMG_NR="2" HEIGHT="3300" WIDTH="2550">
<TopMargin HEIGHT="151" WIDTH="2550" VPOS="0" HPOS="0">
</TopMargin>
<LeftMargin HE<IGHT="2771" WIDTH="143" VPOS="151" HPOS="0">
</LeftMargin>
<RightMargin HEIGHT="2771" WIDTH="143" VPOS="151" HPOS="2407">
</RightMargin>
<BottomMargin HEIGHT="378" WIDTH="2550" VPOS="2922" HPOS="0">
<TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
</BottomMargin>
<PrintSpace>
</PrintSpace>
</Page>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "html.parser")

b_margin = soup.select_one("BottomMargin")

# Remove BottomMargin from the xml
for tag in soup.select("BottomMargin"):
    tag.extract()

# add the `BottomMargin` to the `soup`
soup.printspace.insert_after(b_margin)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<page height="3300" id="Page2" physical_img_nr="2" width="2550">
 <topmargin height="151" hpos="0" vpos="0" width="2550">
 </topmargin>
 <leftmargin he<ight="2771" hpos="0" vpos="151" width="143">
 </leftmargin>
 <rightmargin height="2771" hpos="2407" vpos="151" width="143">
 </rightmargin>
 <printspace>
 </printspace>
 <bottommargin height="378" hpos="0" vpos="2922" width="2550">
  <textblock>
  </textblock>
 </bottommargin>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have many `<page>` in your XML document. `extract()` is not needed, just call `.insert_after()` with your tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<Page ID="Page1" PHYSICAL_IMG_NR="2" HEIGHT="3300" WIDTH="2550">
<TopMargin HEIGHT="151" WIDTH="2550" VPOS="0" HPOS="0">
</TopMargin>
<LeftMargin HE<IGHT="2771" WIDTH="143" VPOS="151" HPOS="0">
</LeftMargin>
<RightMargin HEIGHT="2771" WIDTH="143" VPOS="151" HPOS="2407">
</RightMargin>
<BottomMargin HEIGHT="378" WIDTH="2550" VPOS="2922" HPOS="0">
<TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
</BottomMargin>
<PrintSpace>
</PrintSpace>
</Page>
       
<Page ID="Page2" PHYSICAL_IMG_NR="2" HEIGHT="3300" WIDTH="2550">
<TopMargin HEIGHT="151" WIDTH="2550" VPOS="0" HPOS="0">
</TopMargin>
<LeftMargin HE<IGHT="2771" WIDTH="143" VPOS="151" HPOS="0">
</LeftMargin>
<RightMargin HEIGHT="2771" WIDTH="143" VPOS="151" HPOS="2407">
</RightMargin>
<BottomMargin HEIGHT="378" WIDTH="2550" VPOS="2922" HPOS="0">
<TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
</BottomMargin>
<PrintSpace>
</PrintSpace>
</Page>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for bottom_margin in soup.select('page bottommargin'):
    bottom_margin.find_parent('page').printspace.insert_after(bottom_margin)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<page height="3300" id="Page1" physical_img_nr="2" width="2550">
 <topmargin height="151" hpos="0" vpos="0" width="2550">
 </topmargin>
 <leftmargin he<ight="2771" hpos="0" vpos="151" width="143">
 </leftmargin>
 <rightmargin height="2771" hpos="2407" vpos="151" width="143">
 </rightmargin>
 <printspace>
 </printspace>
 <bottommargin height="378" hpos="0" vpos="2922" width="2550">
  <textblock>
  </textblock>
 </bottommargin>
</page>
<page height="3300" id="Page2" physical_img_nr="2" width="2550">
 <topmargin height="151" hpos="0" vpos="0" width="2550">
 </topmargin>
 <leftmargin he<ight="2771" hpos="0" vpos="151" width="143">
 </leftmargin>
 <rightmargin height="2771" hpos="2407" vpos="151" width="143">
 </rightmargin>
 <printspace>
 </printspace>
 <bottommargin height="378" hpos="0" vpos="2922" width="2550">
  <textblock>
  </textblock>
 </bottommargin>
</page>
```